# Boost Library Import Into Metatrader (MT4) Script File

Tags: function, boost, dll, metatrader4

I am working within a Metatrader script file and need to call a function within a Boost library.  Anyone know if this is possible?  If so how do you configure the import?

Comment: What function do you need to call?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.

Check this out: http://docs.mql4.com/basis/preprosessor/import

If you look at most metaquotes mql examples, they import stdlib and stderror . The built in help section in the editor will also have info on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is really possible.
But all is not as you might imagine.

Of course, it depends on what you want to do, but main idea is to create a DLL and include it to your EA as Dmitry said.

All your functions must be defined like this:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int doSomething(...)
{ ... }
```

So you may call it from your terminal.

Be careful with c++ types in Metatrader.

In a DLL you can do what you want according to your declaration -- with all data you'll get.

Don't forgot to check your DLL for dependencies (using Dependency Walker) to see what other DLLs your library is using (you must provide them to your Metatrader terminal, copy to `terminal.exe` location folder, or add folder with your DLLs to your systems `path`).